# How to show info of how many items are displayed on every page, AngularJs Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My problem here Is how to show how many items are displayed on every page.

Ex. I have 50 items displayed for paging. 10 on every page, so I want to have info about how many items are displaying currently. For example on the first page to be 'Displaying items from 1 to 10' , on the second page 'Displaying items from 11 to 20'...

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>

</div>
```

AngularJs

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 9;
    $scope.start = 0;
    $scope.end = 0;
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }

    for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}

//We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
//let's make a startFrom filter
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/2443/)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First update angular to the latest release, 1.4.8 as of this post.  This is important because after 1.1.5 you can use ternary statement in an expression.  It looks like you have most of your logic in your view, while some might say you should move it to the controller or to some service, it's really up to you at the end of the day.  I have put the logic in the view to match your initial example.

here is the added logic:

```
{{(currentPage)*pageSize}} -
{{(currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1)?
data.length-1:(currentPage)*pageSize+pageSize-1}}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mywjhmfy/